# What is the most efficient way to create a 2d string array of initally repetitive data?

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

In Python, typically to define said game board I would have used the following code:

```
board = [['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'] for i in range(10)]
```

However, using Java the only way I have been able to find so far to produce the same result would be to do:

```java
public static String[][] board = {
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
        {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"}};
```

Surely there must be a more efficient way of doing this. I know I can do it efficiently if it were to be integers, but it has to be strings given the situation. I had thought a for loop would also have applied, but I can't seem to find the right syntax for it; perhaps it isn't applicable for Java. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over each row and use [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-):

```java
public static String[][] board = new String[rows][cols];
static {
    for (String[] row : board) Arrays.fill(row, "0");
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/zH6nlv)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `for` loops to create the 10 rows and 10 columns. So within the first loop (which creates a "row"), you'd add another loop to fill the "columns."

```java
String[][] board = new String[10][10];

// 10 rows
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // 10 columns
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // Set the value of this row/column
        board[i][j] = "0";
    }
}
```

This obviously isn't as elegant as Python's one-line solution, but it does what you need.

There are other ways to do this (such as just adding a full 10-digit array to the `board` array in each loop), but I find this to be best for scalability and readability.

---

For further clarity, if you may possibly need to change the number of rows or columns in the future, it would be better to move those values to variables and use those instead:

```java
int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;

String[][] board = new String[rows][cols];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; i++) {
        board[i][j] = "0";
    }
}
```

This way you only need to update the variables instead of also modifying the `for` loops and array declaration.

Comment: Oh I see.

So, I'd define the board as a 10x10 and then go back and reset the values to "0" allowing them to be used as strings... right?

Comment: Assuming you know the exact size ahead of time, yes. The other answers here so far may be more efficient in terms of lines of code, though. It really just depends on what is more readable to you.

Comment: It will always be the same exact size yes. The only thing to change will be the values of them. Readability is somewhat important here, and I believe your solution is seemingly the best I have seen yet. So thank you very much for the solution; transitioning between Python and Java is proving difficult.

Comment: This is basically the textbook iterative approach.  If you're going to do it using nested for loops operating directly on the array values using a classic iterative style, this would be about as straightforward and clear as you can get.

Comment: @M.Justin Yep, that's exactly what I was going for. This is code that'll be reviewed and I have to explain line-by-line unfortunately to someone with little experience, so this will likely be the best solution I can find.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. Since `Strings` are immutable, it's safe to use `clone()` here. Thanks to [@iota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/iota) for suggesting `setAll`

```
int n = 10;
String[][] arr = new String[n][n];
Arrays.fill(arr[0], "0");
Arrays.setAll(arr, i->arr[0].clone());


for(String[] a : arr) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Prints

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: try something like `arr[1][2] = "2"`. There are exactly two instances `String[10]` in that array: the first subarray (original), and second subarray (clone) repeated till end (String is immutable, (sub)array not)

Comment: @WJS You can use `Arrays.setAll` to avoid the issue: `String[] row = arr[0].clone();Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> row.clone());`

Comment: @WJS No problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hybrid of for loop and manually creating one row of cells.

```java
String[][] board = new String[10][];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    board[i] = new String[]{"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)-based solution to the problem that uses a functional style, rather than an iterative style:

```java
return Stream.generate(() -> 
                Collections.nCopies(10, "0").toArray(String[]::new))
        .limit(10)
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Note that depending on the readability, etc. requirements, a classic iterative style may be deemed more desirable.

### Explanation

[`Collections.nCopies(10, "0")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)) creates a [`List<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of 10 `"0"` values.  This is converted to a `String` array using [`Collection.toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)).  This takes an [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) which generates an array of a given length.  `String[]::new` is a [constructor lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#constructor) which implements `IntFunction<String[]>`, creating an array of the given length.

[`Stream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)) creates an infinite stream with each element created by a call to a given [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html).  In this case, the supplier creates the aforementioned 10-element long list, resulting in a `Stream<String[]>`.  A generator is used, rather than `Collections.nCopies`, since each `String[]` in the `String[][]` needs be a different object.

The infinite stream is limited to just ten elements using [`Stream.limit(10)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)).

Finally, the `Stream<String[]>` is collected into a `String[][]` by using [`Stream.toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)), which works in the same manner as the `Collection.toArray` method already described.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) since 11

```java
String[][] board = new String[10][];
```

1. [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) - for each row repeat `0` ten times and split into an array:

   ```java
   Arrays.setAll(board, i -> "0".repeat(10).split(""));
   ```
2. [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) - in this case, the result is the same:

   ```java
   Arrays.fill(board, "0".repeat(10).split(""));
   ```

Output:

```java
Arrays.stream(board).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How can I fill this 2D array with X characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264494/14940971)</sup>